# How to implement a safe global Instance?

Tags: rust

In Rust, I am trying to find a way to safely set a global `Instant`. `Instant` is perhaps a unique form of a singleton because it has no way to initialize itself through constant function calls. Attempting to initialize a `static Instant` via `Instant::now()` results in the following error:

```
error[E0015]: calls in statics are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants
  --> src/main.rs:45:24
   |
45 | static EPOCH:Instant = Instant::now();
   | 

               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Therefore I am looking for an ideally safe way to do the above. For context, I already have a way to do this using `unsafe` rust:

```
use std::time::{Instant};
use std::mem::{self, MaybeUninit};

static mut MONOTONIC_EPOCH:MaybeUninit<Instant> = MaybeUninit::<Instant>::uninit();

fn set_epoch() {
    unsafe {
        MONOTONIC_EPOCH.as_mut_ptr().write(Instant::now());
    }
}
```

In my use case, I need global monotonic point in time that can be used to track the time since some point in the program execution. Thus, the global `Instant` does not need to be mutable after it's first set. It can be assumed that this initialization would be guaranteed in the use case to occur with only one thread active.

Note: I do need a way to control *when* the initialization of the `Instant` occurs.

Comment: Take a look at `lazy_static` and/or `lazy_cell`. Both `const` and `static` values are instantiated at compile time.

Comment: In this case though, I would need a way to control when the initialization occurs. Does lazy_static offer that ?

Comment: `lazy_static` initialises on first access.

Comment: in that case the first access could just be a "touch" type of access, which works

Comment: There's also an explicit [`initialize`](https://docs.rs/lazy_static/1.4.0/lazy_static/fn.initialize.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `once_cell::Lazy` any of [`sync`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/1.8.0/once_cell/sync/struct.Lazy.html) or [`unsync`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/1.8.0/once_cell/unsync/struct.Lazy.html) versions depending your needs:

```rust
use std::time::{Instant};
use once_cell::sync::Lazy;

static EPOCH: Lazy<Instant> = Lazy::new(Instant::now);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e703d72c593dbb835587c17a88d79620)

If you want to handle when and where initialization is done use [`OnceCell`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/1.8.0/once_cell/sync/struct.OnceCell.html) instead:

```rust
use std::time::{Instant};
use once_cell::sync::OnceCell;

static EPOCH: OnceCell<Instant> = OnceCell::new();

fn main() {
    let instant = EPOCH.get_or_init(Instant::now);
    println!("{:?}", *instant);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=31737f1455dd38511240253e7575780b)